# Array in a textbox C#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I'm new in C#, and I'm trying to show an array in a textbox using window forms.

The problem is that when I give the command `txtTela.Text = tela.ToString();`, the program compiles successfully, but the result in the textbox is `"System.String[]"`, and not the string that I'd like to show.

Image of what is printed in the textbox: https://snag.gy/L34bfM.jpg

```
    public String[] comboPalavra;
    public String []tela = new String[1];

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        comboPalavra = embaralhaPalavra.CarregaPalavra();//Recebe uma palavra e uma dica


        //MessageBox.Show(comboPalavra[0]);

        foreach(char element in comboPalavra[0])
        {
            this.tela[0] = tela + "#";
        }

        txtTela.Text = tela.ToString();
        txtDica.Text = comboPalavra[1].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your string array into single string. You can do this by string.Join().

```
textBox.Text = string.Join(separator, stringArray);
```

or

```
 textBox.Text = string.Join(separator, stringArray.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Comment: Thanks!! But, I've tried this, as I saw in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659409/how-do-you-display-a-string-array-in-a-text-box, but it didn't work...

Comment: @dev-john Show me your string.Join code that doesn't work.

Comment: txtTela.Text = string.Join(separator, tela);

Comment: @dev-john Everything should work fine. Remember to define separator and I hope it is obvious that if you have empty array nothing will be display.

Answer (score 1):

Or with linq expression (using System.Linq):

```
textBox.Text =stringArray.Aggregate((x, y) => x + separator + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined 'tela' as an array of String and applied the .ToString()-method directly to that array-object, which is why it ended in: System.String[]

```
public String []tela = new String[1];
txtTela.Text = tela.ToString();
```

To print a specific element, you need to define which element you want to print:

```
txtTela.Text = tela[0];
```