# How to eliminate delimiters and spaces from user inputed text?

Tags: c#, csv

create a project that will allow the user to enter a mailing address. The address may not contain any leading or trailing spacebars and may not contain the following special characters.
•   Period key (.)
•   Comma (,)
•   Semicolon (;)
The user will enter a mailing address into a Text Box. When the appropriate button is selected, the entered address will be checked for any invalid characters. The resulting/corrected address will then be displayed into a Label.

I have written code but I cannot figure out how to display it in the label box without the period, comma, and semicolon

```
        string wordString;
        char[] delimChar = { ',', '.', ';' };

        wordString = entryTextBox.Text;
        wordString = wordString.Trim();
        string[] delimString = wordString.Split(delimChar);
```

I have no error messages in the code but need some additional help.

Comment: Duplicate explains exactly what you try to do. Problem in code you wrote is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659409/how-do-you-display-a-string-array-in-a-text-box

Answer (score 1):

You could just use regex replace

```
var input = "    P.O, Box123;";
var pattern = @"^ *|\.|,|;";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
PO Box123
```

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B1lNTD)

Comment: That would work except if they enter a different address. I want the user to be able to input any address and it correct it to take out white space, comma, period and semicolon.

Comment: `public string MyAwesomeMethod(string input)... return result;`

Comment: Yes but that helps. Didn't even think to do that. Oops.